# @Async process not immediately giving result while execution

Tags: spring, maven

```
 Main class


@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class LearnAsynchronousApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearnAsynchronousApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("LearnAsynchronous is running");
    }
}

Controller Class

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LearnRestAsyncController {

    @Autowired
    private LearnAsyncService learnasyncService;

    @RequestMapping (value= "async/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAsyncMsg(@PathVariable String name)throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        String msg=learnasyncService.getAsyncMsg(name).get();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(msg,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping (value="log", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> logMsg()throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
    learnasyncService.logMsg();
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}

Service class

package Train.LearnAsync.LearnAsynchronous.service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class LearnAsyncServiceImpl implements LearnAsyncService {

    @Async
    @Override
    public Future<String> getAsyncMsg(final String name) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Execute method Asynchronously. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("---------thread done");
        return new AsyncResult<String> ("Hello! Good Morning. " + name);
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public void logMsg(){
        System.out.println("Execute method Asynchronously." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Today's Date." + new Date());
    }
}

Config Class(@EnableAsync given here)

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class SpringAsyncConfigurer implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }


    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

> Can anyone suggest how to return result immediately, async not
>   working , if i hit by rest call its waiting to complete the hole
>   process , after that only returning the result..
>
> once hit this url from postman http://localhost:8080/async/xyz
>   waiting for complete the process , but @async advantage is thread  shouldn't wait for complete. it should return result immediately.
>
> Waiting for valuable suggestion

Comment: How could you return a response immediately, containing the result of the asynchronous computation, without waiting for the result to be computed? Either you want to return immediately, but you won't have the result, or you want the result, but then you need to wait for it.

Comment: ok Nizet. Thanks